# SSIS: What are rules to import date fields from text files to SQL table

Tags: sql, datetime, ssis

I have created a package in |**SSIS 2012**. The package basically connect to a text files in a predefined location and load data from the text files to the SQL database table. I have one DOB field which is DATE TYPE in the destination SQL table and it was returning error: conversion failed and date out-of-range.

I did not have any luck converting DOB column using the CAST or CONVERT funtion:

> CONVERT(date, DOB, 103)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use DATE data type!!!

Comment: If you have to store dates as a string, always use the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: The conversion process is totally different between DBMS, you should be more specific and even show a concrete example. Then we could tell you if it is a good way of managing these dates.

Comment: You could also consider working with Timestamps in some specific cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some bad data in my input files for the DOB column. For example, DOB: 100-01-01, 29999-05-24; I tried to convert these dates using CONVERT function and it was returning error.

So, I was just selecting records only with valid DOB dates using the query as below and after that I could convert the DOB without any error in this case:

SELECT * FROM MyTableTest WHERE **ISDATE(dob)** <> 1

Comment: `ISDATE()` is not always reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CAST() or CONVERT() functions, when you want convert varchar value to datetime 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Note that no dbms is specified here. CAST is ANSI SQL, but CONVERT is not.